# Did Daesh execute 5000 Yazidi men in August 2014?

Tags: isis

[DailyMail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2792552/full-horror-yazidis-didn-t-escape-mount-sinjar-confirms-5-000-men-executed-7-000-women-kept-sex-slaves.html):

> Full horror of the Yazidis who didn’t escape Mount Sinjar: UN confirms 5,000 men were executed and 7,000 women are now kept as sex slaves ...
>
> Researchers, piecing together reports of attacks, have now concluded that more than 5,000 Yazidi were gunned down ...

The above report is cited in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide_of_Yazidis_by_ISIL):

> The genocide led to the abduction of Yazidi women and massacres that killed at least 5,000 Yazidi civilians

Did Daesh executed at least 5000 Yazidi men in the period before 14 October 2014?